# Integer to Bn conversion

Tags: c#

I have this piece of c# code that I cannot understand.  During the first iteration of the IntToBin loop, I understand that the shift operator convert it to byte value of 7 but on the second pass, the byte value is 224.  How is the 224 achieved.

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IntToBin(2016,2);
        //Console.Write((byte)2016);
    }

    public static byte[] IntToBin(int from, int len)
    {
        byte[] to = new byte[len];
        int max = len;
        int t;
        for (int i_move = max - 1, i_to = 0; i_move >= 0; i_move--, i_to++)
        {

            to[i_to] = (byte)(from >> (8 * i_move));
        }

        return to;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, you have difficulty with this line

```
to[i_to] = (byte)(from >> (8 * i_move));
```

You can easily test that

```
2016 == 7 * 256 + 224
```

Now how to get these numbers?

Shift operator `>>` is, in fact, an *integer division* by 
powers of two:

```
  >> 0 - no division (division by 1) 
  >> 1 - division by 2
  >> 2 - division by 4
  ...
  >> 8 * i_move - dision by 2**(8*i_move) i.e. division by 256 ** i_move
```

while `(byte)` cast is, in fact, *remainder* operator `% 256` 
since `(byte)` returns the *last byte*.

Now let's try to *unwrap* the loop

```
  i_move == 1 // max - 1 where max = 2
  to[0] = (from / 256) % 256;  // = 7

  i_move == 0 
  to[1] = (from / 1) % 256;   //  = 224
```

In general case

```
  to[0]       = from / (256 ** (len - 1)) % 256;
  to[1]       = from / (256 ** (len - 2)) % 256;
  ...
  to[len - 3] = from / (256 ** 2) % 256;
  to[len - 2] = from / (256) % 256;
  to[len - 1] = from / (1) % 256;
```